# JSOM get user's sharepoint groups by AD

Tags: jsom

I use JSOM to get Sharepoint group of my user like this and it's working perfectly :

```
userGroups  = currentUser.get_groups();
context.load(userGroups);
var groupsEnumerator = userGroups.getEnumerator();

while (groupsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var group = groupsEnumerator.get_current();
    groups.push(group.get_title());
}
userConstants.user.groups = groups;
```

So I am in 2 groups by my username.
And I am in 1 group AD, this group AD is in a SharePoint group.

In "userConstants.user.groups", I have my 2 groups I am by my username, but I don't retrieve my group I am by AD.

I hope I was clear.

Thank you.